# Is there a formula for expressing a function applied frational, complex, etc times?

Tags: functions

Is there any formula for example saying $f^{\frac{1}{2}}(x)$ or $f^{\pi}(x)$? I tried to derive it but couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: There are many ways to define something like applying it half a time, even in the "simple" case of [2×2 matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix). So you probably need more context to make a relevant choice.

Comment: No - not in general.  But there are cases where this makes some kind of sense